# Using DSolve and NDSolve for 1D steady-state diffusion equation with a reaction term

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, nonlinear, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve for a 1D steady-state diffusion equation (Fick's Second Law/Heat Equation) with a reaction term. I wanted to compare using both `DSolve` and `NDSolve`.

However, when running the code, I get multiple errors:
[image]

```
(*L+rUnderoverscript[\[Equilibrium], d1, k1]R*)
k1 = 0.00193
d1 = 0.00700
K1 = d1/k1
NT = 1.7
(*Total Receptors(NT) = r+R*)
R = (NT*u[x])/(K1 + u[x])
r = NT - R
RL = (d1*R) - (k1*u[x]*r)

diffCo = 0.0001; (*Diffusion coefficient*)
bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x] == 1, x == 0], DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, x == 100]};
eqn = diffCo*u''[x] + RL == 0;

solDSolve = u[x] /. First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u[x], {x, 0, 100}]

solNDSolve = 
 NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}]
```

Am I setting something up incorrectly?
Thank you.

Comment: Your code does not return those errors. In particular, notice that you use `u[x, t]` in the definitions, and you mix that with `u[x]` in thee equations and boundary conditions. Please amend the code to show exactly what you used.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry about that. I initially tried solving with time dependency before switching to steady state and forgot to adjust those terms. 

I fixed them and am getting the errors I mentioned.

Comment: Your problems seem to stem from the choice of the FEM method. `NDSolve` seems to work fine if you remove the `Method` specifications. Do you have to / want to use FEM specifically?

Comment: @MarcoB even when removing it, I still get the CoefficientArrays and NDSolve error. I don't need it to use FEM specifically.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `CoefficientArrays::poly` signifies that `FEM` only works for linear ODE's, which is a bit strange to me. Or maybe I am not understanding it.

This type of error message has been [reported](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=QK4ZW5H4C-XXjwS8xaPYCg&q=coefficientarrays%3A%3Apoly&oq=coefficientarrays%3A%3Apoly&gs_l=psy-ab.12..0i71k1l2.0.0.0.549768.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.Xm5thCD10aI) quite a few times but for PDE's not ODE's.

As suggested in the comment you should remove the `Method` but still you and I (V. 11.2) are getting the same error. I think, it's because the way the boundary conditions are defined (I suspect, `NDSolve` is calling `FEM` by default). If we consider the boundary conditions in the more conventional way, everything seems to work just fine,

```
solNDSolve = NDSolve[{eqn, u[0] == 1, u[100] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 100}]
```

Comment: Although, when I plot that solution, it's just a linear line when I thought it should be nonlinear. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AhWee Why you think this ode must have a nonlinear solution?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding I expected the concentration at x=0 to decay/deplete at the rate RL. I tried making the other end of the boundary much larger in the hopes to see at what point did the concentration reach 0. However, when I try this boundary condition, it just moves the 0 point to whichever x, I choose to make it. Also, the y axis along the plot just shows "1."

Unless I'm setting up the plot wrong. I put `Plot[Evaluate[u[x] /. solNDSolve], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]`

Comment: @AhWee Try this `u[x] /. solNDSolve /. x -> 100` you will see that the bc at `x=100` is satisfied.

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[u[x] /. solNDSolve /. x -> 100], {x, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> Full]' correct? In this case, I just get a horizontal line at 1.

Comment: @AhWee you should get a line but not horizontal

Answer (score 1):

Things are very simple. Your differential equation reduces to `(u''[x] == 0` .

```
k1 = 0.00193;
d1 = 0.00700;
K1 = d1/k1;
NT = 1.7;
R = (NT*u[x])/(K1 + u[x]);
r = NT - R;
RL = (d1*R) - (k1*u[x]*r);
diffCo = 0.0001;

bc = {u[0] == 1, u[100] == 0};
eqn = Rationalize[diffCo*u''[x] + RL == 0, 0] // Simplify

(*   (u''[x] == 0   *)

sol = First@DSolve[{eqn, bc}, u, x]

(*   {u -> Function[{x}, (100 - x)/100]}   *)

ndsol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}]

Plot[u[x] /. ndsol, {x, 0, 100}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Simplify` on the equations and `"MaxCellMeasure"` (as a String) and things work out as expected.

```
solNDSolve = 
 NDSolve[{eqn // Simplify, bc}, u, {x, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}]
```